# Using Material-UI's Grid component, how do I get one cell to take up the remaining horizontal width?

Tags: css, reactjs, grid, material-ui

I'm trying to use material-ui's Grid component in my React 16.13.0 application.  I want to have a row with three items.  The first two items should only take up as much space as they need to (I don't want to hard code pixel values if possible).  I would like the third item to take up the remaining horizontal space and float the furthest to the rigth (I discovered React doesn't like "float: right" as a style, though).  I have this

```
const styles = (theme) => ({
  root: {
    textAlign: "left",
    margin: theme.spacing(2),
    paddingBottom: theme.spacing(1),
    color: theme.color.secondary,
  },
  cardHeader: {
    paddingBottom: theme.spacing(0),
  },
  cardContent: {
    width: "100%",
    paddingBottom: theme.spacing(1),
  },
  rowBody: {
    width: "100%",
    flexWrap: "nowrap",
    alignItems: "center",
  },
});
...
      <CardContent className={classes.cardContent}>
        <Grid container className={classes.rowBody}>
          <Grid item>
            <img height="20" src={require('../../img/apple.svg')} alt="" />
          </Grid>
          <Grid item>
            {title}
          </Grid>
          <Grid item>
            <InfoIcon />
          </Grid>
        </Grid>
```

But unfortunately, this renders everything bunched up together

[image]

How can I adjust the styles to do what I want?

**Edit:** This is what is displayed based on the answer given by @Mohsen007 ...

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Follow the code below:

```
rowBody: {
    width: "100%",
    flexWrap: "nowrap",
    alignItems: "center",
    display: "flex",
},

<Grid container className={classes.rowBody}>
     <Grid item>
         <img height="20" src={require('../../img/apple.svg')} alt="" />
     </Grid>
     <Grid item style={{flex: 1,}}>
         {title}
     </Grid>
     <Grid item>
         <InfoIcon />
     </Grid>
</Grid>
```

Comment: Thanks for this, although this isn't quite what I was going for (included a scren shot in my question with the results of your suggestion).  Everything is now centered, but I prefer the row to be left aligned and only the 3rd cell (the one with the info icon) to take up as much space as possible.  Finally, I'd like the info icon to be right-aligned in its cell.

Comment: Oh sorry...ok,Is this what you want that info icon stick in right side of screen?

Comment: I think you forgut add "flex: 1" to second Grid,isn't it??